# How to configure Nginx reverse proxy properly?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have one create-react-app application, containerized with below *Dockerfile*.

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.5-alpine
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY conf /etc/nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The conf.d for Nginx

```
upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}

server {
  listen 5000;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

}
```

I have one expressjs application, containerized with below *Dockerfile*.

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install --production
COPY . /app
CMD node index.js
EXPOSE 5000
```

I build docker image for each app so I have to docker image:

1. NginxImage (ReactJS Application)
2. NodeJsImage

I try to run both of the image using docker with below *docker-compose*:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  app:
    image: NginxImage
    hostname: app
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
    networks:
      - local_deploy
  api:
    image: NodeJsImage
    hostname: api
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - local_deploy
networks:
  local_deploy:
    driver: bridge
```

But when I try to open the reactjs application within browser, and when the reactjs app call **http://api:5000** I got error **ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

I try to access the api within container

```
docker exec -it app /bin/sh
```

and I can get the response from the api

```
# curl api:5000
```

Is my reverse-proxy is not properly configured?

Comment: The React application runs in the browser, not in Docker; it can't see the Docker-internal hostnames `app` or `api`.  You might serve both the compiled application and the backend proxy on the same Nginx port at different locations and then your browser application can make a request to `/api/wherever` without needing to know a host name.

Comment: You should access the app via the proxy using the NGINX port `80` (that can then forward to the API service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the hint [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze), [@Beppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9095551/beppe-c) and [@Yusuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674072/yusuf-ibrahim). In my case I just change the API endpoint to the app address it self.

Example if the app run on

```
localhost:3001
```

Then I set the api endpoint to be

```
localhost:3001/api
```

In the nginx config I add another location in the server block with re-write condition

```
upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api
  }
}
```